# Error when upgrading to Drupal 8.7.1 on module menu_link_content

Tags: database, navigation, upgrading

When running database updates (on domain.com/update.php) from 8.6.15 to 8.7.1, I got the following error:

```
module menu_link_content
Update make_menu_link_content_revisionable
Custom menu links have been converted to be revisionable.
Failed: InvalidArgumentException: Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values. in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->expandArguments() (line 735 of /baseserverpath/public_html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php)
```

I can see the error "Placeholders must have a trailing [] if they are to be expanded with an array of values" happens on several different occasions in Drupal 8, as there are some different posts on the issue dating back to 2016. But I cannot find it related specifically to module 'menu_link_content'. I wonder if the problem could be related to a special character that cannot be correctly escaped.

The upgrade doesn't work and some other database upgrades get stuck in the queue, since this one for 'menu_link_content' cannot be completed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, but when I had run the update with **drush updatedb -y** command, I resolved that.